# How to scrollToElement using angular-scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [Angular Scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/) and once you hit a certain page I fire a function to scroll to an id. I'm getting the following error on the code below:

> TypeError: $document.scrollToElement is not a function

```
initHelp();

function initHelp() {
    console.log('initHelp');
    $document.scrollToElement('#chart-help', 500).then(function() {
        console && console.log('You just scrolled to chart-help!');
    });
}
```

The docs from [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/)

```
.scrollTo( element [, offset, [, duration [, easing ] ] ] )

Alias of .scrollToElement.

.scrollToElement( element [, offset, [, duration [, easing ] ] ] )
```

Comment: No, didn't realize this required jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
var chartHelp = angular.element(document.getElementById('chart-help'));

$document.scrollToElement(chartHelp, 30, 500).then(function() {
    console && console.log('You just scrolled to chart-help!');
});
```

Also from their docs, I was missing the offset number:
`$document.scrollToElement(someElement, offset, duration);`